# What is "same quarter" meaning about histogram?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

In "Adaptive document image binarization" paper (link: http://www.mediateam.oulu.fi/publications/pdf/24.p) I found SDM, TBM algorithm for Text/Image Segmentation,
But I can't understand what "same quarter" is in the followed this paragraph.

1. If the average is high and a global histogram peak is in
   the same quarter of the histogram and transient differ-
   ence is transient, then use SDM.
2. If the average is medium and a global histogram peak
   is not in the same quarter of the histogram and transi-
   ent difference is uniform, then use TBM.

I know that a quarter meaning is 1/4. But i think that quarter is different meaning.. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After skimming the paper very quickly, I found two possible ways to interpret this.

- From the current bin, choose a quarter of the histogram by looking 1/8th to the left and 1/8th to the right. i.e. if your histogram has 256 bins, and you are at bin 50, the quarter you are looking for is [18, 81]. So if the average is high and the peak lies in [18,81], use SDM.
- Divide the entire histogram into quarters, and check which quarter your current bin lies in. i.e. if your histogram has 256 bins, divide it into [0, 63], [64, 127], [128, 191], [192, 255]. If your current bin is 50, you are in quarter 1, and so if the average is medium and the peak lies anywhere outside quarter 1, use TBM.

Based on intuition and mathematical sense, option 1 is more likely. But I would try both and see which implementation gives better results.

Comment: I forgot this question.. coz so busy until today;;; thanks for replying.. actually I'm poor at english.. so I need dictionary for understand your explaning.. but I have no much time..
Next time I will try to understand your explain.
Thanks for explaining. I'm happy coz you answer politely and detaily.